# What is `$Action.Custom_Object__c.CreateFromLookup`?

Tags: custom-button, action

When creating a custom button, I see an $Action value I can't find documentation on - `$Action.Custom_Object__c.CreateFromLookup`.  It's not on the list of [Valid Values for the $Action Global Variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm).

It only seems to work for buttons on `Other_Obj__c` for `Custom_Object__c` where `Other_Obj__c` has a lookup to `Custom_Object__c`.

The closest I can find is the poorly documented part of the UI API at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_lookup.htm#stq=createfromlookup&stp=1

The result of `{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.CreateFromLookup)}` on a `Other_Obj__c` page button seems to send me to the `Custom_Object__c` tab.